# Not able to copy specific pages of word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, com, document

I am trying to cut specific pages of my word document(.docx), say 2, 4. I am using `for` loop to traverse as per the page gave splitting it based on `,`.Below is the code for the same

```
if (startEnd.Contains(','))
{
    arrSpecificPage = startEnd.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSpecificPage.Length; i++)
    {
        range.Start = doc.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, arrSpecificPage[i]).Start;
        range.End = doc.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, arrSpecificPage[i]).End;
        range.Copy();
        newDocument.Range().Paste();                    
    }
    newDocument.SaveAs(outputSplitDocpath);
}
```

but the issue with this code is that its just copying the last page only to the new document i.e `4` in this case. How to add `2` as well? What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Is it that after the first paste, what was pasted is still selected, so the 2nd paste overwrites the first?  If so, you need to 'unselect' after each paste.

Comment: @Neil i tried to get `newDocument.unselect` but can not find it. How to do that?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? You never followed up...

Answer (score 2):

Since you always specify the entire document "range" as the target, each time you paste the entire content of the document is replaced.

It's correct that you work with a `Range` object and not with a selection, but it helps if you *think about* a Range like a selection. If you select everything (Ctrl+A) then paste, what was selected is replaced by what is pasted. Whatever is assigned to a Range will replace the content of the Range.

The way to solve this is to "collapse" the Range - think of it like pressing the Right-arrow or left-arrow key to "collapse" a selection to its start or end point. In the object model, this is the `Collapse` method that takes a parameter indicating whether to collapse to the start or end point (see the code below).

Note that I've also changed the code to use `document.Content` instead of `Document.Range`. `Content` is a property that returns the entire body of the document; `Range`is a method that expects a start and end point defining a `Range`. Using the property is the preferred method for the entire document.

```
if (startEnd.Contains(','))
{
    arrSpecificPage = startEnd.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSpecificPage.Length; i++)
    {
        range.Start = doc.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, arrSpecificPage[i]).Start;
        range.End = doc.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, arrSpecificPage[i]).End;
        range.Copy();
        Word.Range targetRange = newDocument.Content
        targetRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
        targetRange.Paste();                    
    }
    newDocument.SaveAs(outputSplitDocpath);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error as `This method or property is not available because no text is selected.` at `range.Copy()` How to correct it?

Comment: @Lara I didn't change anything in your code for the copying part - I only added the little bit at the end. Was that not working in your original code? You only mention that it's copying only the last page... Or is this happening only at the end?