# Loop through directory and append to file

Tags: c#, ms-word, directory, office-interop

I am trying to select a path, then I want to read the directories. In each directory there are multiple Word files, I want to open each Word file, copy its contents and paste it in a new word document.

Example if I have 6 Word files in a directory, I want to open a new Word document, then open the first document in the directory, copy its contents and paste it to the new document, and loop until all documents are read.

So far I'm able to loop over the docs , but the newly created word file is only getting the last opened document. Below is my code.

```
namespace combiner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // For optional parameters create a missing object    
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            // Create an object of application class    
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            // add a document in the Application
            Document adoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            // declare variables for setting the position within the document    
            object start = 0;    
            object end = 0;

            // create a range object which starts at 0    
            Range rng = adoc.Range(ref start, ref missing);       

            string path = @"C:\demo";    

            string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] ora = Directory.GetFiles(files[i], "*.docx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string f in ora)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(f);
                    textBox1.Text = f.ToString();

                    // insert a file
                    rng.InsertFile(textBox1.Text, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                    // now make start to point to the end of the content of the first document
                    start = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;

                    // create another range object with the new value for start
                    Range rng1 = adoc.Range(ref start, ref missing);

                    // insert the another document
                   rng1.InsertFile(textBox1.Text, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                    // now make start to point to the end of the content of the first document
                    start = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;
                }

                // make the word appliction visible

                WordApp.Visible = true;
                adoc.SaveAs2(@"D:\fulltest.docx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you identify the newly created word documents ? you have to identify that in someway or else your process may go to infinite loop.

Comment: THERE ARE NO NEWLY CREATED WORD DOCUMENTS , ONLY ONE DOCUMENT WILL CONTAIN ALL THE DATA READ FROM THE OTHER DOCUMENTS

Comment: so what you want is like read the data from all documents and combine the data into a single document right ?

Comment: 100 % , but keep in mind that the root directory might contain multiple folders and every folder will contain word files within

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to copy specific pages of word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554269/not-able-to-copy-specific-pages-of-word-document)

Comment: You'll find the necessary approach described in the Answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554269/not-able-to-copy-specific-pages-of-word-document/52572431#52572431.